# Efficient alternative to Stack<Double>

Tags: java, generics, stack, primitive

I'm writing a performance-critical method in Java which uses a stack of `double` values to store the (x, y) coordinates of points. At the moment, I'm using `Stack<Double>`, but I realize that due to the cost of autoboxing, this might cause some performance issues. The coordinates usually change between calls, which is why caching the `Double` wrappers wouldn't help.

Therefore, I'm looking for a hypothetical class, let's call it `DoubleStack`, with behavior and interface similar to `Stack<T>`, but operating on primitives only. Is there an oft-used class with such behavior, or better yet, a library consisting of primaries-storing alternatives to popular containers, including lists, stacks and queues?

Comment: Is the stack the appropriate data structure for your algorithm?  If so, ignore possible performance issues until you have hard evidence that the stack is a performance bottleneck.  If you have a performance problem you should then profile your code and invest in the areas the profiler says are slow.  What you are doing right now is [Premature Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: If the stack is indeed a performance bottleneck, I suppose you could easily implement your own datastructure based on a `double[]`. The amount of code necessary wouldn't be too much, especially if you don't need to implement all the interfaces of `Stack<T>`, but still enough that I would recommend to follow Jim's recommendation.

Comment: Use a search engine of your choosing to search for "java primitive collection"; you will find libraries which do this.

Comment: There are many libraries which support primitive wrappers, though none do just stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment about premature optimization, but just for the fun of it, here's a trivial DoubleStack implementation:

```
public class HeresYourDoubleStack {
  private int size = 0;
  private double[] values= new double[16];

  public int size() {
    return size;
  }

  public double pop() {
    if(size==0)throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return values[size--];
  }

  public void push(double value) {
    resizeIfNecessary();
    values[size++]=value;
  }

  private void resizeIfNecessary() {
    if(values.length==size){
      double[] tmp = new double[size * 2];
      System.arraycopy(values,0,tmp,0,size);
      values=tmp;
    }
  }
}
```

Not tested, and definitely not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries that provide data structures for primitive types.
One example is [FastUtil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it), which provides a class `DoubleStack` which does exactly what you want.
An alternative might be [Trove4J](http://trove.starlight-systems.com), which provides a class `TDoubleStack`, and there are likely other libraries as well, but the two mentioned I've worked with.

Trove4J was kind of a standard for a long time, but seems not to get many updates any more, while FastUtil seems to be more actively developed. Also, in some of my (biased?) tests, FastUtil was faster in a number of cases, although I tested mostly for Maps, not Stacks.

Comment: You forgot Eclipse Collections, Koloboke and HPPC: http://java-performance.info/hashmap-overview-jdk-fastutil-goldman-sachs-hppc-koloboke-trove-january-2015/